# How Do I Resolve Links with Python?

Tags: python, http, parsing, url, hyperlink

This function takes a string as an input, and if the string starts with `http://` or the string starts with `https://`, the function will assume that the string is an absolute link. If the URL starts with `/`, the function will convert it to an absolute link.

Note that `base` is a global variable for now. My main concern is that this function is making too many assumptions. Is there a way to accomplish the task of resolving URLs without so many assumptions?

```
def get_url(item):
    #absolute link
    if item.startswith('http://') or item.startswith('https://'):
        url = item
    #root-relative link
    elif item.startswith('/'):
        url = base + item
    else:
        url = base + "/" + item
    return url
```

Comment: Try using the [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) module.

Comment: If you don't mind, Could you implement this function using the urlparse module. If not thats fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use [urljoin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) from the [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) module.

```
from urlparse import urljoin

base = 'http://myserver.com'

def get_url(item):
    return urljoin(base, item)
```

`urljoin` handles absolute or relative links itself.

**Examples**

```
print get_url('/paul.html')
print get_url('//otherserver.com/paul.html')
print get_url('https://paul.com/paul.html')
print get_url('dir/paul.html')
```

**Output**

```
http://myserver.com/paul.html
http://otherserver.com/paul.html
https://paul.com/paul.html
http://myserver.com/dir/paul.html
```

Comment: You have to keep in mind that we don't know if item is a relative link or an absolute link. or if item is even a link for that matter.

Comment: Does my edit clarify the first point? If it were not a link what would you expect the function to do?

Comment: Why use a regular expression instead of python string method startswith?  I'm probably missing the point.

Comment: My apologizes , that was for the post below.

Answer (score 0):

1-Use regex

2-Add a trailing `/` to you base url

```
import re        
base = 'http://www.example.com/'

def get_url(item):
    #absolute link
    pattern = "(http|https)://[\w\-]+(\.[\w\-]+)+\S*"  # regex pattern to approve http and https started strings
    if re.search(pattern, item):
        url = item
    #root-relative link
    else:
        url = base + item.lstrip('/')
    return url
```

Comment: Why use a regular expression instead of python string method startswith? I'm probably missing the point.

Comment: @RickyWilson : It's reduced and more clear, when you're going to match a string pattern better go with regex instead of playing with string methods